# navigation component clear backstack except the top fragment

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

i want to clear fragment backstack except the top fragment which is declared as `startDestination` in `nav_graph`. i tried below codes to achieve it but i could not success. its removing all the fragments and when the back button pressed the application is closing.

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/paymentStatusFragment"
        android:name="com.gymat.gym.payment_mvp.PaymentStatusFragment"
        android:label="PaymentStatusFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/payment_succesfull">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_paymentStatusFragment_to_navigation_purchases"
            app:destination="@id/purchasesFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/nav_graph"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>
```

Comment: Instead of using `app:popUpTo="@+id/nav_graph"` use `app:popUpTo="@+id/purchasesFragment"`. The **popUpTo** remove the recent fragments up to the  `id` passed, from the backstack.

Comment: @Kakyire not working.

Comment: Try to also set app:popUpToInclusive as "false"

Answer (score 0):

fixed with adding `popUpToInclusive = "false"` and `app:popUpTo="YOUR FRAGMENT ID TO NAVIGATE AFTER POP BACK"`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/paymentStatusFragment"
    android:name="com.gymat.gym.payment_mvp.PaymentStatusFragment"
    android:label="PaymentStatusFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/payment_succesfull">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_paymentStatusFragment_to_navigation_purchases"
        app:destination="@id/purchasesFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/navigation_home"
        app:popUpToInclusive="false"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/enter_from_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/exit_to_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/enter_from_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/exit_to_right"/>
</fragment>
```